# Regex for 0-360 and null

Tags: regex, null

I am trying to find regular expression for my project. The regular expression should either accept values between 0 and 360 or empty(null) value.

Comment: Please take the habit of including your attempt when asking a question, it's easier for everyone.

Comment: Please invest more time into your question(s). A good read is [John Skeets: Writing the perfect question](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints).

Comment: I will take your comments on board and be a better contributor to the stack overflow community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slightly simplified regex of @aelor

```
^(?:36[0]|3[0-5][0-9]|[12][0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])?$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/puwc-zu29botbKgP)

Answer (score 1):

you need this:

```
^(?:\s*|0|(?:36[0]|3[0-5][0-9]|[12][0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9]))$
```